# Как реализовать правильный обмен данными с COM-портом?

Tags: c#, асинхронность, serial, com-port, rs232

Имеется счётчик учёта электроэнергии с фирменной программой-конфигуратором. Необходимо реализовать похожий, но ограниченный функционал чисто для опроса определённых стандартных показателей со счётчиков в роде текущей потребляемой мощности, накопленной активной, реактивной энергии и т. д.
Опрос проводится с помощью собственного протокола обмена байт-командами через COM-порт в шестнадцатеричном виде. 
Вкратце, пытаюсь реализовать асинхронное чтение с помощью Invoke-методов, и, скорее всего, ввиду моего, мягко говоря, скромного опыта, здесь точно работает запись в порт, и аппарат присылает ответ, но вот сам ответ возращается, скажем так, "кусками". 
Вот как монитор активности порта видит запрос-ответ с помощью фирменного конфигуратора, всё чётко и аккуратно:
[image: Запрос-ответ фирменного конфигуратора]
Однако, код отрабатывает ну очень грязно. Меня смущают многочисленные оповещения насчёт тайм-аутов. Может, что-то с ними не так? При открытии порта я указал их равными по 200 мс (в итоге взял как предлагаемое конфигуратором значение, но пробовал и другие (20, 500, 1000...)). И, как я упоминал, сообщение рвётся по байтам. 
[image: Запрос-ответ кода]
А у меня стоит задача читать, естественно весь приходящий массив байт и пока хотя бы в виде строки выводить в listbox. В дальнейшем, конечно, ещё нужно будет парсить все массивы на данные. Но это уже другая история, хотя тоже пока малопонятна. Прилагаю начальный простой код, с помощью и пытаюсь реализовать обмен с устройством через COM.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace test_Counters003
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static SerialPort Port0 { get; private set; }

        public void Openport()
        {
            Port0 = new SerialPort("COM7", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            Port0.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            Port0.ReadTimeout = 200;
            Port0.WriteTimeout = 200;
            Port0.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Port_DataReceived);
            Port0.Open();          
        }

        void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
                BeginInvoke(new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Port_DataReceived), sender, e);
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            char[] values = indata.ToCharArray();
            foreach (char letter in values)
            {
                int value = Convert.ToInt16(letter);
                string hexOutput = String.Format("{0:X}", value);
                Console.WriteLine(hexOutput);
            }            
        }

        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ct = cts.Token;
            byte[] wrbuf = new byte[256];
            var stream = Port0.BaseStream;
            try
            {
                byte[] writebuf_test = { 0x5C, 0x00, 0x38, 0xB0 };
                Port0.Write(writebuf_test, 0, writebuf_test.Length);
                while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    var actRead = await stream.ReadAsync(wrbuf, 0, wrbuf.Length, ct);
                    if (actRead == 0)
                        return;
                }                
            }
            catch (IOException io)
            {
                if (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                    Console.WriteLine(io.Message);
            }
```

Просьба подсказать что делаю не так, какие источники изучить. MSDN на эту тему, тематические форумы продолжаю штудировать, схожие темы находил. Некоторые предлагаемые решения несколько прояснили ситуацию, по крайней мере, дав совет использовать асинхронные методы, но всё же до конца пока не удаётся решить этот вопрос.
Заранее благодарю за уделённое внимание.

Answer (score 1):

То, что посылка приходит не целиком - нормально. Нужно склеивать приходящие куски в один пакет, и следить, когда он будет завершен - по последовательности-терминатору, по длине, ещё как-то - в зависимости от протокола.

С таймаутами что-то странное. Обычно секунда стоит, 200 мс ничего особо не изменят, проблемы могут быть только при физических неполадках. В настройках всё совпадает (9600 я вижу в обоих случаях, остальное по картинке непросто увидеть) ?

**Edit**

Я сразу не обратил внимание, что после обработчика события  `Port_DataReceived` идёт код нажатия кнопки, в котором посылается команда **и читается ответ**. Зачем нужно это чтение **при наличии асинхронного обработчика** вышеуказанного события? Вероятно, это действие и сбивает с панталыку. Отправили команду в порт  - всё, больше делать нечего, система известит о приходе данных

Надо только не забыть, что обработчик работает в дополнительном потоке. А вот отправку в потоке делать не обязательно (я правильно понимаю, что модификатор `async` для этого?)

Comment: Да, настройки совпадают. Параметры соединения использовал также исходя из настроек конфигураторов по умолчанию. Кстати, имеются даже 2 версии оных, и обе работают отлично. Вроде бы, тут и ошибиться негде. Только, да, поналачу также спутал системный таймаут со временем ожидания ответа. Вы верно указали, там 1000 мс. Но это снова не исправляет ситуацию.
![Параметры соединения](https://ibb.co/b7R11YM)

Comment: Думаю, стоит попробовать убрать stream и всё после write (см. дополнение к ответу)